# How can I get the status of the "pressed" property of a button in ExtJS?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have created a toggle button in ExtJS as:

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'Edit Mode',
    id: 'editID',
    action: 'myToggle',
    pressed: false,
    enableToggle: true,
    margin: 5,
    handler: function (btn, e) {
        editMode(btn); // checks the status of the toggle button
    }
}
```

In some part in my script I want to check if the button is selected or not.
I have tried several ways like:

```
var isChecked = Ext.get('editID').pressed; # gives undefined
```

Or

```
var parent_sub_id_isChecked = Ext.get('editID').dom.pressed; # also undefined
```

How can I get the status of the "pressed" property of a button in ExtJS?

Comment: You can just use  var isChecked  = btn.pressed  in your handler to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should nail it

```
Ext.getCmp('editID').pressed
```

Working code [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/10vo)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! That was it! :)